# How to implement specific criteria into compareTo() method

Tags: java, compareto

Driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle c1 = new Circle(1, "BLUE", true);
    Circle c2 = new Circle(2, "BLUE", true);
    Circle c3 = new Circle(3, "BLUE", false);
    Circle c4 = new Circle(4, "BLACK", true);

    System.out.println("c1 ? c1 " + c1.compareTo(c1));
    System.out.println("c1 ? c2 " + c1.compareTo(c2));
    System.out.println("c1 ? c3 " + c1.compareTo(c3));
    System.out.println("c1 ? c4 " + c1.compareTo(c4));

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(1, 1, "BLUE", true);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(2, 2, "RED", true);
    Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(4, 4, "GREEN", false);
    Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(4, 4, "GREEN", true);

    System.out.println("r1 ? r2 " + r1.compareTo(r2));
    System.out.println("r1 ? r2 " + r1.compareTo(r2));
    System.out.println("c1 ? r2 " + c1.compareTo(r2));
    System.out.println("r3 ? r4 " + r3.compareTo(r4));

}
```

GeometricObject:

```
public int compareTo(GeometricObject otherfigure) {
    if (this.getArea() == otherfigure.getArea()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (this.getArea() > otherfigure.getArea()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Right now I can only compare based on areas, I'm not sure how I would go about adding the other two criteria listed below into my method.

How would I add the criteria if the object is a circle and blue that it is greater than any other object regardless of area, and if the object is transparent (filled = false) then it contributes only 50% of its area?

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax would be to say if the object is a circle && this.color = "blue" that would fulfill the first criteria. And for the second criteria would I just say something like if (this.filled = false) divide area by 2 to account for 50%?

Comment: What does it mean to say that some circle is greater or less than some rectangle?

Comment: It's based off the area of the object other than the 2 criteria I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

To fullfill requirements II I would Add a method to GeometricObject like colorDependentArea()

```
public int colorDependentArea(){
       if(!this.filled){
           return this.area/2;
       }else{ 
           return this.area;
       }

}
```

and use this method in the compare to instead of getArea().

```
public int compareTo(GeometricObject otherfigure) {
    if (this.colorDependentArea() == otherfigure.colorDependentArea()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (this.colorDependentArea() > otherfigure.colorDependentArea()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: How about simetry? Next equation must be true `blueCircle.compareTo(rectangle) == - rectangle.compareTo(blueCircle)`. But in your code `rectangle.compareTo(blueCircle)` doesn't take into acount "blue circle" rule.

Comment: For some reason when it compares C1 to C4 it gives -1 instead of 1 when I am using your first solution that you had for criteria 1.

Comment: I removed the code since it wasn't correct see talex comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can take transparencyInto account by using `derivedArea = area * (filled?1.0:0.5)`

If you whant to treat circles in some specific way you can add check into `compareTo` method:

```
if(this instanceOf Circle && this.isBlue()){
     if(!(otherfigure instanceOf Circle && otherfigure.isBlue()){
         return +1;
     } else {
         // fall back to default behaviour if both object blue circles
     }
} else if (otherfigure instanceOf Circle && otherfigure.isBlue()){
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: When comparing c1 to c4 it gives the value -1 instead of 1, what is causing this?

Comment: Circle 4 is black so it should return 1 because when comparing c1 to c4, c1 is blue therefore it will always be greater. However it is not working.

Comment: I added this line `else if (otherfigure instanceof Circle && !("blue".equalsIgnoreCase(this.color))) {
   return 1;` however it still doesn't seem to work it just goes back to the default of comparing the areas.

Comment: why ` !("blue".equalsIgnoreCase(this.color)`? Try debugger then.

Comment: I'm not sure. I keep changing it around but nothing seems to work. c1 ? c4 is supposed to = 1 because c1 is blue and c4 is black.